# Expected absolute difference between 1's and 0's

Tags: probability, expectation, binomial-distribution

Given a random binary string with size n, what is the expected absolute difference between the number of ones and zeros? no need for an accurate expression just an asymptotical bound.

My answer (I'm looking for a better one) is:

let the string be of size $2n$ (for comfortability). 
let $X$ be the absolute difference. $X$, of course, must be even

$X=2k$ if and only if the number of ones is $n+k$ or the number of zeros is $n+k$. I.e $\Pr(X=2k) = 2\cdot \binom{2n}{n+k}\cdot 2^{-2n}$.

so $E[X] = \sum _{k=0}^n2k\cdot Pr(X=2k) = \frac{4}{4^n}\sum _{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{n+k}k$

using wolfram alpha I can calculate the sum above and get that $E[X] =\Theta(\sqrt n)$ but I'm looking for a simpler solution

Comment: For large $n$ you can approximate binomial with gaussian.

Comment: By symmetry / linearity of expectations, this should be zero... Unless you mean absolute difference?

Comment: Based on your comment to my answer, you intend "absolute difference," not "difference." I have edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a string of length $2n$, the distribution of the number $Y_n$ of ones is binomial $(2n,\frac12)$. The number of zeroes is $2n-Y_n$ hence the absolute difference between the number of ones and zeroes in a string of length $2n$ is $X_n=|Y_n-(2n-Y_n)|=2|Y_n-n|$.

By the central limit theorem, $Z_n=(Y_n-n)\sqrt{2/n}$ converges in distribution to $Z$ standard normal.

This result (does not imply per se but) can be enhanced to the convergence of the moments of $Z_n$ to the moments of $Z$. Thus, $$E(X_n)=2\sqrt{n/2}E|Z_n|\sim \sqrt{2n}E|Z|=\sqrt{2n}\sqrt{2/\pi}=2\sqrt{n/\pi}$$ This confirms that $E(X_n)=\Theta(\sqrt n)$, and refines this estimate into the asymptotics

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{E(X_n)}{\sqrt n}=\frac2{\sqrt\pi}$$

Comment: very nice, I ran a simulation on my computer and it showed that the limit you calculated should be in fact $\sqrt\frac{2}{\pi}$ so maybe you have a mistake with the constants. I think it happened when you changed from a string of length $2n$ to a string of length $n$

Comment: Did you run the simulations with strings of length $n$ or $2n$?

Comment: $n$. I don't think it's necessary to assume that the length is even in your proof.

Comment: The formulas in my post involve $X_n$, corresponding to strings of length $2n$ (as mentioned in the first sentence). Thus it seems no modification is needed here -- or one changes every definition in the post.